# Is there a way to customize how the value for a custom Model Field is displayed in a template?

Tags: django, model, field

I am storing dates as an integer field in the format YYYYMMDD, where month or day is optional.

I have the following function for formatting the number:

```
def flexibledateformat(value):
    import datetime, re
    try:
        value = str(int(value))
    except:
        return None
    match = re.match(r'(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)$',str(value))
    if match:
        year_val, month_val, day_val = [int(v) for v in match.groups()]
    if day_val:
        return datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.date(year_val,month_val,day_val),'%b %e, %Y')
    elif month_val:
        return datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.date(year_val,month_val,1),'%B %Y')
    else:
        return str(year_val)
```

Which results in the following outputs:

```
>>> flexibledateformat(20100415)
'Apr 15, 2010'
>>> flexibledateformat(20100400)
'April 2010'
>>> flexibledateformat(20100000)
'2010'
```

So I'm wondering if there's a function I can add under the model field class that would automatically call `flexibledateformat`.

So if there's a record
    r = DataRecord(name='foo',date=20100400)
when processed in the form the value would be `20100400` but when output in a template using `{{ r.date }}` it shows up as "April 2010".

## Further clarification

I do normally use datetime for storing date/time values. In this specific case, I need to record **non-specific dates**: "*x* happened in 2009", "*y* happened sometime in June 1996".

The easiest way to do this while still preserving most of the functionality of a date field, including sorting and filtering, is by using an integer in the format of `yyyymmdd`. That is why I am using an `IntegerField` instead of a `DateTimeField`.

This is what I would like to happen:

1. I store what I call a "Flexible
   Date" in a `FlexibleDateField` as an
   integer with the format `yyyymmdd`.
2. I render a form that includes a
   FlexibleDateField, and the value
   remains an integer so that functions
   necessary for validating it and
   rendering it in widgets work
   correctly.
3. I call it in a template,
   as in {{ object.flexibledate }} and
   it is formatted according to the
   flexibledateformat rules: `20100416`
   -> April 16, 2010; `20100400` -> April 2010; `20100000` -> 2010. This
   also applies when I'm not calling it
   directly, such as when it's used as
   a header in admin
   (`http://example.org/admin/app_name/model_name/`).

I'm not aware if these specific things are possible.

## Also

I have already written a template filter that can perform this function --
(`{{object.flexibledate|flexibledateformat}}`) --
but I'd rather not have to call the filter every time I want to output one of these values. Except when outputting the form, I pretty much never want to see the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most *djangoish* way of accomplishing a similar effect would be to define a custom method on a model:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    date = models.IntegerField()
    ...

    def flexibledate(self):
        return flexibledateformat(self.date)
```

You can use it in a template like this:

```
{{ r.flexibledate }}
```

I also wonder why are you using an IntegerField instead of a native DateTimeField.

**Update:** You can still use the custom method as an option for `list_display` in Django Admin. If you want the column header to say something else then simply the method's name use the "short_description" option, like this:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    date = models.IntegerField()
    ...

    def flexibledate(self):
        return flexibledateformat(self.date)
    flexibledate.short_description = 'Date'
```

and then you just use it the same way you would use an ordinary field:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'flexibledate')
admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

Comment: "I also wonder why are you using an IntegerField instead of a native DateTimeField."

Because as far as I understand, `2009-04-00` and `2009-00-00` are not valid values for a `DateTimeField`.

In my models I'm not using models.IntegerField(), I'm using FlexibleDateField(), a custom model field. I'm well aware that I can add a function to the model, but what I'm hoping is there is a special function for model fields analagous to how  `__unicode__` works: where I would output a value that is a `FlexibleDateField`, it would output the integer formatted using `flexibledateformat`.

Comment: Well, you can play with getters and setters, but I think defining a method and being able to easily access both the "real" and the "flexible" value is a much cleaner solution (in oposite to blocking an access to the raw value). It is also consistent with how Django itself handles similar situations.

Comment: One area that I'd really like to get this working is in /admin/app_name/model_name/ where I am using these as columns in the list view. Basically, it needs to be able to sort by the value (in Integer form) and *then* output it using the flexibledateformat function. I'm not at all sure how this would work.

Comment: Just put `ordering = ['date']` in model's meta class, and `'flexibledate'` in model's ModelAdmin list_display option (`list_display = ('title', 'flexibledate')`). Another reason to keep those two separate.

Comment: Oh, and you can specify the column's header doesn't necessary have to be a method's name. I updated my original post for more information.

Answer (score -1):

That is not necesary, read about [humanize](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturalday) and filtertag [time](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#time)

Comment: Unless I'm misreading the docs, these are for DateTime values.