# Custom model field rendering in Django template

Tags: django, model, custom-fields

I have extended `django-markdown` with a custom model field which allows one to define classes:

```
from django.db import models
from django_markdown.fields import MarkdownField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    text = MarkdownField()

class MySecondModel(models.Model):
    description = MarkdownField()
```

Now, when it comes to rendering those fields in the template it is possible to do:

```
{% load markdown_tags %}
{{ model.text|markdown }} {{ model2.description|markdown }}
```

However, that seems to defeat the object of creating a custom model field in the first place (to enhance DRYness), and is preferably to be avoided at all costs.

So, is there a way to do just `{{ model.text }} {{ model2.description }}` without loading the template tags and without filtering by somehow defining a `render` method on the custom field?

A similar question has already been asked: [Is there a way to customize how the value for a custom Model Field is displayed in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648346/is-there-a-way-to-customize-how-the-value-for-a-custom-model-field-is-displayed), but the answer entails adding a method to the Model. That would mean adding methods to `MyModel` and `MySecondModel`, as well as any subsequent ones. Again this defeats the entire object of DRY!

**NB** Both model classes are subclasses of something else, so defining a mixin is feasible, but there must surely be a nicer way!

Comment: any idea about overriding the `__str__` method of the field?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation as you. I figured that I could solve it using a mixin to the Model class.

It seems to work as intended, but I'm not really sure if it's the right way to do it. Feels like a dirty hack that I don't fully understand.

You should of course replace the method _shout() with something more useful.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.db import models


class LoudModelMixin(object):

    """ adds the 'html' property to a Model
    Lets regular django models be louder!

    Regular field:
    >>> blogpost.title
    'hello world'

    Same field, but louder.
    >>> blogpost.html.title
    '<strong>HELLO WORLD!</strong>'
    """

    @property
    def html(self):
        return self._HTML(self)

    class _HTML(object):

        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent

        def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
            raw_text = getattr(self.parent, attr, *args)
            assert isinstance(raw_text, str), 'only words can be loud.'
            return mark_safe(self._shout(raw_text))

        def _shout(self, raw, tag='strong'):
            """ Do something useful with the text here. """
            return '<{tag}>{text}!</{tag}>'.format(
                tag=tag, text=raw.upper()
            )


class Blogpost(models.Model, LoudModelMixin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
```